# How use Spring Security 3 on Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, spring-security

I have read a lot of tutorials about using Spring Security 3 on Struts 2. But I can't make it work :/.

I can't find a "Dummy step by step guide" about implement this framework on Struts 2.

Here is what I have:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">



    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
   <display-name>cv</display-name>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>example/HelloWorld.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd/spring-spring-context-2.5.xsd-3.1.1.RELEASE.xsd
">


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http realm="Project Realm" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" filters="none"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/auth/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.jsp?login_error=1"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/auth/login.jsp"/>
    <remember-me />
</http>

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" filters="none" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/search.action*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" /><!-- Never reach -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" /><!-- Never reach -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />           
    <form-login login-page="/login.action" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout.action" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <user name="customer" password="customer" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</b:beans>


</beans>
```

And my HelloWorld.jsp

```
<body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1><br />
        <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
         This session will be visible to an admin only.<br/>
         You are an Administrator.<br/>
        </sec:authorize>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
         This session will be visible to an Customer only.<br/>
         You are an Customer.<br/>
        </sec:authorize>
        ${HelloMessage}<br />
        <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a>
    </body>
```

I want to test how the privileges works using the tag "isAnonymous" showing that block of text, but I can't make it work

:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Spring Security's filter chain to the web.xml.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This goes after your Struts filter.  This will allow Spring Security to check/block the request prior to Struts being handed the request.

Assuming the user is allowed to access the content Spring Security will set up a SecurityContext object that will make allow the JSP tags work.